# Dart dynamic type implementation

Tags: dart, dynamic

I tried figure out what is a dynamic type in Dart actually, read a lot of questions and articles but cant fully understand. Usually the answers point to docs where it is written that dynamic is a type. So I think about it like a some portion of memory in heap where the variable points to, and the concrete type depend on which data stored in this concrete place in the memory, but we can change data in this place from smaller to bigger say from int to the object, and it will work. How it is actually implemented is it reallocated in this case or something else? Thanks!

Comment: Everything in Dart is an object. `dynamic variable` just disables static type-checking for the reference `variable`; it doesn't affect what `variable` refers to.

Comment: Thanks. So conceptually dynamic is a reference to some memory where object lives, and this reference can be switched to point to another memory with other object? All this with no type checking. Did I get it right?

Comment: The only important part is that `dynamic` is not type-checked.  All variables are references to objects, and all non-`final` variable can be reassigned to refer to different objects.  Neither of those properties is special to `dynamic`.

Comment: Yes, I agree but the main difference that dynamic reference point to different data type and therefore different memory sizes, so as I understand dynamic is non typed pointer. Which represented by Dart as a special type but technically it is not a type. Seems  make sense..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Effective Dart: Design](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-using-dynamic-unless-you-want-to-disable-static-checking) article, the `dynamic` type is used when the user needs to explicitly disable the type checking.

In general, it's the same type as `Object?`, which means that it can be any object or null.

At the same time, the static analyzer allows using any operation on dynamic objects without casting. This may cause runtime errors, but is useful when working with JSON and similar.

Comment: so it is not a type? I was confused with "The type dynamic is a static type which is a supertype of all other types..." - paragraph 20.7 Type dynamic in Dart specs

Comment: It is. The `dynamic` type is used to represent any other type and null, but also to disable the static type checking. That means that the static analyzer will not warn the user if he tries to use a method that may not be present in the object, for instance. I recommend you to read the article from my answer, it has many examples of using `dynamic` in Dart and many more

Comment: ```The type dynamic not only accepts all objects, but it also permits all operations. Any member access on a value of type dynamic is allowed at compile time, but may fail and throw an exception at runtime. If you want exactly that risky but flexible dynamic dispatch, then dynamic is the right type to use.``` - Effective Dart: Design

Comment: I read it, and I understand and successfully used it, but cat't find any concrete information about internals of  the dynamic implementation. From one hand it acts like a type, and from other not. The main question is how it is conceptually layout in AOT compilation. I think it works like I wrote above in main question comments. But cant be sure am I wrong or not. Duplicate: "So conceptually dynamic is a reference to some memory where object lives, and this reference can be switched to point to another memory with other object? All this with no type checking."

Comment: @Parafin `dynamic` should not affect memory layout at all.  Everything is an object, and all variables, regardless of what their type is statically known to be (which might be `dynamic`), are just references to objects.

Comment: @jamesdlin, yes, I got it, i meant that layout once ) Thanks